# Can I get microcontroller burner software for Linux on internet

Tags: microcontroller

I was thinking to buy a microcontroller burner online and it doesn't give a software to burn with. After buying the burner, where can I get the burner software? Can I download it on the internet? My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Which family(s) of microcontroller are you planning to work with?

Comment: Atmega 16, 32 and PIC mc's @Dave Tweed

Comment: I think the most common "microcontroller burner" is probably the common household stove. A microcontroller *programmer* is a different matter.

Comment: @user291957, for the AVR controllers I would suggest AVRdude. Once you understand what commands to use, downloading the intel HEX information to the board can be encapuslated in a makefile. When I was to send the program over I simply type into the console `make install` and off it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the microcontroller family.

Typically a burner program will support a variety of different microcontroller hardware dev boards, prototype boards and burners, and program hundreds of different types of micros, as long as they are all from the same family.

For the Atmel AVR used in Arduino etc, use [AVRdude](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) and you might start [[here]](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/avrdude.html) for instructions and examples of its use.

For the TI MSP430, you can use [MSPdebug](http://mspdebug.sourceforge.net/) which will work with boards like the [Launchpad](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430g2) and [EZ430](http://www.ti.com/tool/ez430-f2013) and many others to program any MSP430 which supports the SBW interface (not all of them do, but a lot). Others require JTAG programming hardware which I believe MSPdebug also supports.

Ubuntu probably already has packages of these two : try `apt-get install avrdude` and `apt-get install mspdebug` and find out!

In addition to the burner you would need a cross-compiler probably based on gcc, such these for the [MSP430](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msp430ada/) or [AVR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avr-ada/) if you want to program in Ada, or this [MSP430 C compiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mspgcc/). C compilers for the AVR are available in many distros including Ubuntu already.

For other micros such as the Microchip PIC and ARM-Cortex I'll let someone else get you started as I'm less up to date with them. Actually I'm *hoping* someone will answer with the equivalent tools for them...

Comment: thank you for your help. I am understanding some stuff in these embedded systems. I have a usb asp programmer and working with avrdude with the sudo command.But the sinaprog software is not able to find the programmer. I think the problem with that is i have to run the program with admin permissions but have no idea how to do it. Can u help me @Brain

Comment: Use the sudo command, or run the command as root, or have your sysadmin change the udev rules to allow the programmer to run without admit permissions.